# How to check if both the value exists or only one value exists in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have an Object as below :

```
{"user": {
    "name": "Harry Peter",
    "phoneNumber": "12345",
    "products": [
        {
            "type": "card",
            "accountId": "5299367",
       },
        {
            "type": "Loan",
            "accountId": "5299365", 
        },
        {
            "type": "card",
            "accountId": "8299388", 
        },
     ]}
}
```

What I need to find out if the user has both loan and card or just loan as user product.

Is there any built in function in javascript or angular to find it.

is someone has any suggestion how to do it. Please help.

Comment: use lodash to find any

Comment: You don't want to iterate and just want to know any built-ins ?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja I need to find out if is there is any way to achieve this by using any built ins or other solution.

Comment: @Toretto You can loop over products and get unique types to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `filter` array method.

```js
var obj = {
    "user": {
    "name": "Harry Peter",
    "phoneNumber": "12345",
    "products": [
        {
            "type": "card",
            "accountId": "5299367",
       },
        {
            "type": "Loan",
            "accountId": "5299365", 
        },
        {
            "type": "card",
            "accountId": "8299388", 
        },
     ]
  }
};
      
var loans = obj.user.products.filter(function(product){
      return product.type === "Loan";
});
      
console.log("Loans: " + loans.length);
      
// supposing that the user has either a Loan or a card. You could
// easily now find out if the user has only loans as below:
      
if(loans.length === obj.user.products.length){
    console.log("The user has only loans");
}else{
    var cards = obj.user.products.length - loans.length;
    console.log("The user has "+loans.length+" Loan(s) and "+ cards+ " Card(s).");
}
```

For further info about this method, please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

> What I need to find out if the user has both loan and card or just
>   loan as user product.

Based on the above snippet, by using the `filter` method and comparing the `length` of the `loans` with the `length`  of the `products`, you can answer you question.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over `products` and get unique types

```js
var data = {
  "user": {
    "name": "Harry Peter",
    "phoneNumber": "12345",
    "products": [{
      "type": "card",
      "accountId": "5299367",
    }, {
      "type": "Loan",
      "accountId": "5299365",
    }, {
      "type": "card",
      "accountId": "8299388",
    }, ]
  }
}
                 
var result= data.user.products.reduce(function(p,c){
  if(p.indexOf(c.type)<0) p.push(c.type)
  return p;                 
}, [])
    
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```js
var obj = {
  "user": {
    "name": "Harry Peter",
    "phoneNumber": "12345",
    "products": [{
      "type": "card",
      "accountId": "5299367",
    }, {
      "type": "Loan",
      "accountId": "5299365",
    }, {
      "type": "card",
      "accountId": "8299388",
    }, ]
  }
};

var results = {};

obj.user.products.reduce(function(oldval, item) {
  oldval[item.type] = true;
  return oldval;
}, results);

console.log(results.card && results.Loan); // paints true
// Additionally, results have all the information about the unique value for type, hence, can be used as per the need
```

Answer (score 0):

Same Iteration solution, but immediately gives you if `type` is different from `Loan`.

```js
var obj = {"user": {
    "name": "Harry Peter",
    "phoneNumber": "12345",
    "products": [
        {
            "type": "card",
            "accountId": "5299367",
       },
        {
            "type": "Loan",
            "accountId": "5299365", 
        },
        {
            "type": "card",
            "accountId": "8299388", 
        },
     ]}
};
      
function haveDifferentProducts(products){
    var isDiff = false;
    products.forEach(function(product){
       isDiff = product.type != "Loan"; //checks if type not loan
    });
    return isDiff;
}
console.log(haveDifferentProducts(obj.user.products))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use Array [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

**Working demo :**

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "user": {
    "name": "Harry Peter",
    "phoneNumber": "12345",
    "products": [
      {
        "type": "card",
        "accountId": "5299367",
      },
      {
        "type": "Loan",
        "accountId": "5299365", 
      },
      {
        "type": "card",
        "accountId": "8299388", 
      },
    ]   
  }
};

var totalLoan = jsonObj.user.products.filter(function(item){
      return item.type == "Loan";
});


var totalCards = jsonObj.user.products.filter(function(item){
      return item.type == "card";
});

if(totalCards.length < 1 && totalLoan.length < 0) {
  console.log("Only loan");
} else if (totalCards.length > 0 && totalLoan.length < 1) {
  console.log("Only card");
} else {
  console.log("Both card as well as loan");
}
```